# How to do something for each file starting with test_*.py in a Makefile

Tags: python, file, testing, makefile

Im trying to write a makefile target that runs a command for each of my test files (test_[name].py). I'm wondering how to use the `foreach` command to do something for those files, and only those files.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

```
.PHONY: all

TEST_PY:=$(wildcard test_*.py)

$(foreach i,$(TEST_PY),$(info $(i)))

all:
    @:
```

It will print the name of each file, the list of files is provided by the function **wildcard**. The documentation of these functions are at [GNU Make Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Functions.html)

The "@:" is to avoid the message "make: Nothing to be done for 'all'."

Answer (score 0):

Also found that this work quite well for what I was trying...

```
test: $(TEST_DIRECTORY)/*/*
   for file in $^ ; do \
      ...
   done
```